# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS: Etherrnet Connection DNS address could not be found DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE

Tags: network-manager, dns, ethernet

I have run into this problem before using ubuntu 20.04.03 desktop and I had to reinstall the OS. I cant afford to do that this time so I hope you can help. I have no idea how to diagnose the issue, but was working one moment, my computer froze up a bit so I rebooted, when it came back on it wont connect to any website.

DNS adress could not be found Diagnosing the problem.
DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE

is what I get from my brave browser while safari likes to load the
cached part of the page and tell me that I lack internet connection. Please advise , Im in the middle of developing!

I am using ethernet, all my other devices connect to the router via wifi, and the connection says its going through when i check using the GUI.

```
ping www.google.com
```

returns:

```
Temporary Failure in Name Resolution
```

Then

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

[image]

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132760/discussion-on-question-by-t0admomo-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-etherrnet-connection-dns).  Let's continue there.

Comment: Yes it works, its a wired connection

Comment: After a lengthy debugging session, `systemd-resolved` is not properly handling DNS lookups to other DNS servers, which is in turn causing problems for Internet lookups.  As a result, Firefox and other web browsers all fail hard with DNS failures.  We've done a workaround to disable SystemD's `resolved` and disable NetworkManager's DNS handoff to `resolv.conf` and overrode your system's DNS to use `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` (Google DNS) to get you online and operational, which was your goal today.  We'll debug SystemD later and I'll give that answer here when we do.